# How to solve Unsatisfied Dependency Exception? Problem with Annotation Qualifiers

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I trying to implemet a singleton design pattern in Spring. I am running in an error wwhen running my code.

my configuration file is:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("springdemo3") 
public class AppConfig {

}
```

I have created a service interface as follow:

```
package springdemo3;

public interface Service {
  void doSomething();
}
```

I have created interface called Pump as follow;

```
public interface Pump {
 void features();
}
```

Created two types of pumps electric and water pump both implementing pump interface, as follow:

```
package springdemo3;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ElectricPump implements Pump{

@Override
@Primary
   public void features() {
      System.out.println("This pump is an "
            + "electric pump");
   }    
}

package springdemo3;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class WaterPump implements Pump{

   @Override    
   public void features() {
       System.out.println("This pump is pumping"
            + " water");
   }    
}
```

My serviceB bean is created as follow:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component //This is a bean
public class ServiceB implements Service{
   @Autowired  
   @Qualifier("electricpump")      
   private Pump mPump; 

   public Pump getMpump() {
     return mPump;
   }
   public void setMpump(Pump mPump) {
     this.mPump = mPump;
   }

   public void doSomething() {
     System.out.println("We have a water"
            + " pump running here");
     mPump.features();
   }    
}
```

While my main function is as follow:

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
/*** Here I'm not using XML configuration and using Singleton Design Pattern */
public class SpringDemo3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {        
           
   ApplicationContext context = 
           new  AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);

   ServiceB mServiceB = context.getBean(ServiceB.class);
   mServiceB.doSomething();
 
 }    
}
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceB': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mPump'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'springdemo3.Pump' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier("electricpump")}
```

I'm trying to understand Spring Framework. Please note all these classes are in the same package. What is it that I'm doing wrong here?

But this worked
[image]

Comment: @Rouliboy can you help here?

Comment: Try using this property so you can see in the logs which beans get wired with wath names: "logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG" I'm not 100% sure but it could be that @Qualifier("electricpump") needs a capital P for Pump. If you throw me a link of a repo I can build the project and help you look for the issue if this doesn't solve it.

Comment: @H3AR7B3A7 let me share the git link.. just in a minute

Comment: @H3AR7B3A7 I have sent you invite link in githup

Comment: @H3AR7B3A7 https://github.com/nhlapoth/SpringDemo44/invitations

Comment: Sorry to keep you waiting, I created a pull request and formulated an answer. Using an IDE like Intellij IDEA will help you out to not spend hours looking for small mistakes like these. The intellisense would have spotted the spelling mistake in your bean name and alerted you about it. You get a 30-day free trial to the professional version and as a student you can get a license for free. There is also the community edition which works equally as great for your use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment `@Qualifier("electricpump")` needed a capital P for Pump.

I created a branch and made a pull request to your project:

- Restructured your project
- Added a maven pom.xml (because I couldn't run your project)
- Fixed the bean name 'electricPump'

*Consider always using some project management tool. This way among other things, people can easily set up you project and help you out.*

Comment: Thank you.  Your solution is right but I was not using xml configuration, see with my configuration class AppConfig. OMG! you're have been right all along, there was something wrong with my @Qualifier and it was not only capital 'P'. I spelled it wrong, I left out 'c'. Instead of 'electricPump', I have been typing 'electriPump'.. Man!! I took hours to see this (I think I was tired) but thanks to you guys. After fixing that, above code run well. Typos can mess you up well but I'm now going to look into using xml like you did...Yoo but the code looks long but I really appreciate it my king.

Comment: That XML is just a maven pom, it gets generated if you create a spring project using https://start.spring.io/ or the wizard in Intellij. The dependencies you can just copy paste from maven https://mvnrepository.com/. It will make sure all the jars your project depends on get loaded when someone downloads and builds your project. If you don't like the looks of the verbose pom.xml, you can always try gradle. Gradle uses a scripting language and is both faster and more compact. Some people don't like it because of the added complexity, but you can do a lot more with it than with Maven. Cheers

Comment: Thanks. I'm definitely going jump onto your solution. I need to understand different options out there. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please bear in mind that default naming convetion for spring beans is camel case, so in fact the proper name for your bean should be `electricPump` instead of `electricpump`. Then, you should be able to autowire the bean.

Other than that, field autowiring is not recommended as it makes unit testing of your service more difficult. Use constructor autowiring preferably.
Also, you've placed `@Primary` in the incorrect position, as it is the annotation which marks the bean to be the first preference for autowiring. It can be used on method level but it only makes sense when the method is defining a bean and is annotated with `@Bean` annotation as well.

Comment: It isn't really helpful to repeat what people already mentioned in the comments. Although you are right, @Primary annotation or field autowiring isn't going to fail compilation. These 'comments' are more suitable in the comment section of the question, as they aren't a solution to the issue.

Comment: @captainAye Thanks!! The issue was with my typo. I need to find material on how to use these annotations.

Comment: For Bean annotation, you can read this article https://www.journaldev.com/21577/spring-bean-annotation. For a detailed information, you can also reference excellent spring docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-java-bean-annotation.

Comment: For primary annotation, javadoc should be clear https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html